# titanium appcelerator failed building on android with error cardview/R.java error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, android, titanium, appcelerator

im running appcelerator 4.7.1 with SDK 5.5.1 on a android device with android 6.0 and JDK 1.7.0_80 on Macbook with El Capitan

I'm trying to run a mobile project for Android, nothing more than a index controller with a imageview

When running, it always get stuck on 
building,and returns several errors on a R.java file (which is autogenerated). Tried with all other SDK versions and other android devices but always return with the same problem. Any advice ?

Here's the log, error is at the end

```
    Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.5.1
    Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
    2016-10-12T18:11:24.862Z | TRACE  | set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
    2016-10-12T18:11:24.863Z | TRACE  | checking credentials for existing session
    2016-10-12T18:11:25.127Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
    2016-10-12T18:11:25.133Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.319Z | TRACE  | registry result 200 application/json undefined undefined false undefined
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.332Z | TRACE  | registry returned { expiry: 1476900686299 }
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.333Z | TRACE  | refresh session expiry to:  1476900686299
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.335Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1476900686299 false
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.335Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud config file: /Users/********/.acs
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.340Z | TRACE  | found Arrow Cloud login { mid: '028afc67106f7b611adbd9fc2d71989feab852bd',
      publishPort: 443,
      publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
      username: '******************',
      cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3A%2BlpTYaE0y3V2MOQYREwPE2LE.zzKQfmJSZTOZnzMi6j00Kaz%2BPzkKyVX%2BNf0SnavuCgQ; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 24 Oct 2016 19:19:25 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
      defaultEP: 
       { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
         publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.341Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1477336765000 ]
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.341Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.343Z | TRACE  | getCredentials() session:
    {
      "ipaddress": "192.168.0.96",
      "username": "********@gmail.com",
      "password": "<OMITTED>",
      "session": "<OMITTED>",
      "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
      "environment": {
        "name": "production",
        "isProduction": true,
        "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
        "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
        "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
      },
      "token": "<OMITTED>",
      "fingerprint": "028afc67106f7b611adbd9fc2d71989feab852bd",
      "fingerprint_description": "Mac OSX Serial Number: C02J3015DV33",
      "org_id": 100012327,
      "expiry": 1476900686299
    }
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.344Z | TRACE  | loading plugins for command "run"
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.400Z | TRACE  | run search paths:
    [
      "/Users/*******/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package",
      "/Users/*******/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules",
      "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/node_modules",
      "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/Contents/node_modules",
      "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/AppceleratorStudio.app/node_modules",
      "/Applications/Appcelerator Studio/node_modules",
      "/Applications/node_modules",
      "/node_modules",
      "/Users/********/.appcelerator/.npm/lib/node_modules"
    ]
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.401Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/appc.js
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.822Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 419ms /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/appc.js
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.822Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.825Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 1ms /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/arrow/appc.js
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.828Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/arrow
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.832Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.832Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.834Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.836Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the following plugins:
    ["titanium"]
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.837Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
    2016-10-12T18:11:26.838Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.493Z | TRACE  | registry result 200 application/json undefined undefined false undefined
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.494Z | TRACE  | registry returned { expiry: 1476900687485 }
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.494Z | TRACE  | refresh session expiry to:  1476900687485
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.495Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1476900687485 false
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.496Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
    2016-10-12T18:11:27.516Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1476224773068
    10/12/2016, 1:11:32 PM
    Operating System
      Name                        = Mac OS X
      Version                     = 10.11.6
      Architecture                = 64bit
      # CPUs                      = 8
      Memory                      = 4294967296
    Node.js
      Node.js Version             = 4.2.6
      npm Version                 = 2.14.12
    Titanium CLI
      CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
    Titanium SDK
      SDK Version                 = 5.5.1.GA
      SDK Path                    = /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA
      Target Platform             = android
    Command
      /usr/local/bin/node /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build run --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 5.5.1.GA --project-dir /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND --target emulator --android-sdk /Users/*********/android-sdk --device-id Sony_Xperia_Z3 --skip-js-minify --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 59505 --config-file /var/folders/_5/2zcsntt15ld__mvbthh_mp6c0000gp/T/build-1476295887497.json --no-banner --project-dir /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND
    [INFO] :   Installing module: ti.mely-android-0.1.zip
    [INFO] :   Installing module: ti.mely-iphone-0.3.zip
    [ERROR] :  Failed to unzip module "/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/ti.mely-android-0.1.zip"
    [ERROR] :  Failed to unzip module "/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/ti.mely-iphone-0.3.zip"
    [INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=ti.cloud version=3.2.9 platform=commonjs deploy-type=development path=/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.9
    [INFO] :   Found better matching module id=ti.cloud version=latest platform=commonjs deploy-type=development path=/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.11
    [INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.0 
    [INFO] :   Deploy type: development
    [INFO] :   Building for target: emulator
    [INFO] :   Building for emulator: Sony_Xperia_Z3
    [INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK API: 23
    [INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
    [INFO] :   Signing with keystore: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/dev_keystore (tidev)
    [INFO] :   Debugging disabled
    [INFO] :   Profiler disabled
    [INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/build-manifest.json does not exist
    [INFO] :   Found Alloy app in /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/app
    [INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/*********/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/alloy/bin/alloy compile /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=development,target=emulator --no-colors
    [WARN] :   Generated "/i18n" directory is not ignored by Git, please add it to your .gitignore
    [WARN] :   Generated "/platform" directory is not ignored by Git, please add it to your .gitignore
    [INFO] :   [config.json] config.json unchanged, using cached config.json...
    [INFO] :   ----- MVC GENERATION -----
    [INFO] :   [global style] loading from cache...
    [INFO] :   [index.xml] view processing...
    [INFO] :   style:      "index.tss"
    [INFO] :   view:       "index.xml"
    [INFO] :   controller: "index.js"
    [INFO] :   created:    "Resources/android/alloy/controllers/index.js"
    [INFO] :   created:     "Resources/android/alloy/styles/index.js"
    [INFO] :   
    [INFO] :   [app.js] using cached app.js...
    [INFO] :   
    [INFO] :   ----- OPTIMIZING -----
    [INFO] :   - android/XMLTools.js
    [INFO] :   - android/alloy.js
    [INFO] :   - android/reste.js
    [INFO] :   - android/vastapi.js
    [INFO] :   - android/ws.js
    [INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/localStorage.js
    [INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/properties.js
    [INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/sql.js
    [INFO] :   
    [INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 1.35585s
    [INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
    [INFO] :   Launching emulator: Sony_Xperia_Z3
    [INFO] :   Running: /Users/*********/android-sdk/tools/emulator "-avd" "Sony_Xperia_Z3" "-port" "5554" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128" "-sdcard" "/Users/*********/.android/avd/Sony_Xperia_Z3.avd/sdcard.img"
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/footer_merida.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/footer_shows.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/head100enforma.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headatascate.jpg
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headatascate.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headcancunvive.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/header_1.PNG
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/header_2.PNG
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headgarabatoz.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headsipsebits.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headsipsedeportes.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headsipsenot.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/headsmz21.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/p.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/row100enforma.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowAtascate.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowCancunVives.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowGalaTV.jpg
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowGarabatOz.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowSipseBits.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowSipseDeportes.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowSipseNoticias.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowSmz21.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/rowZonaVIP.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/header_1.JPG
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/header_2.JPG
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portada100forma.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaAtascate.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaCancunVive.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaGarabatOz.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaSipseBits.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaSipseDeportes.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaSipseNoticias.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/portadaSmz21.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/row100forma.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowAtascate.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowCancunVive.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowGarabatOz.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowSipseBits.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowSipseDeportes.jpeg
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowSipseNoticias.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/shows/rowSmz21.png
    [WARN] :   Overwriting file /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/Resources/images/smz21.jpg
    [INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
    [INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/titanium_prep.macos "mx.com.sipse.playand" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/assets" "alloy/CFG.js" "app.js" "XMLTools.js" "alloy/backbone.js" "alloy/constants.js" "alloy/controllers/BaseController.js" "alloy/controllers/index.js" "alloy/styles/index.js" "alloy/sync/localStorage.js" "alloy/sync/properties.js" "alloy/sync/sql.js" "alloy/underscore.js" "alloy/widget.js" "alloy.js" "reste.js" "vastapi.js" "ws.js" "ti.cloud.js" "_app_props_.json"
    [INFO] :   Writing /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets/app.json
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-accelerometer.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-map.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-calendar.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.res.zip
    [INFO] :   Extracting module resources: /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.res.zip
    [INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
    [INFO] :   Generating i18n files
    [INFO] :   Generating /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/res/values/theme.xml
    [INFO] :   Packaging application: /Users/*********/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen" "-M" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/res" "-I" "/Users/*********/android-sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar" "-F" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview" "-S" "/var/folders/_5/2zcsntt15ld__mvbthh_mp6c0000gp/T/116912-29170-hthoh9/res" "-S" "/var/folders/_5/2zcsntt15ld__mvbthh_mp6c0000gp/T/116912-29170-buh75e/res" "-S" "/var/folders/_5/2zcsntt15ld__mvbthh_mp6c0000gp/T/116912-29170-65amjy/res"
    [INFO] :   Emulator is booted
    [INFO] :   SD card not required, skipping mount check
    [INFO] :   Emulator ready!
    [INFO] :   Building Java source files: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac "-J-Xmx1024M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "/Users/*********/android-sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/titanium.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-accelerometer.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-map.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-calendar.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar:/Users/*********/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar:R.class:AssetCryptImpl.class:SipsePlayAndActivity.class:SipsePlayAndAppInfo.class:SipsePlayAndApplication.class" "-d" "/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/bin/classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@/Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/java-sources.txt"
    [ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
    [ERROR] :  
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2036: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_1_a2a53ecc14=0x7f020000;
    [ERROR] :                                  ^
    [ERROR] :    (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2036: error: illegal underscore
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_1_a2a53ecc14=0x7f020000;
    [ERROR] :                                      ^
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2036: error: <identifier> expected
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_1_a2a53ecc14=0x7f020000;
    [ERROR] :                                                 ^
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2037: error: <identifier> expected
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_2_7701f31964=0x7f020001;
    [ERROR] :                                 ^
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2037: error: illegal start of type
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_2_7701f31964=0x7f020001;
    [ERROR] :                                            ^
    [ERROR] :  /Users/*********/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/SIPSE Play AND/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2037: error: <identifier> expected
    [ERROR] :          public static final int 01_2_7701f31964=0x7f020001;
    [ERROR] :
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was wondering, I created a fresh new mobile project, added my old files (controllers, views, styles, assets, etc.), added the facebook module and run it, worked like a charm.